# How do I make a search where my search string contains a slash in Axios

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have a search string that looks like `ABC/23/54` to pass as a string to Axios.
But Axios says  **AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404**.
Like it changes the path so no request gets to the db.
How would I solve this?

```
const key = "ABC/23/54"

Axios.get(
`http://127.0.0.1:5000/items/search/${key}.then(...))
```

Comment: This is not specific to axios. It's a general thing for all HTTP communication. Special characters are encoded when part of an URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try with the encodeURIComponent function

```
Axios.get(
`http://127.0.0.1:5000/items/search/${encodeURIComponent(key)}.then(...))
```